# Adding keyboard actions in 2.82

Tags: shortcut

Where is the **Add New** keyboard shortcut feature in 2.8?
Why 2.7X keymap in Blender 2.8 doesn't have keyboard shortcuts from 2.7X?
Why exporting a keymap from 2.7 imported in 2.8 doesn't work?
How to copy keymap from 2.7 to 2.8 if the Export/Import feature doesn't function?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add shortcuts by right-clicking a menu item or button and choose "Assign shortcut"